# flann/util/serialization.h class std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >' has no member named 'serialize'

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a project Kintinuous used pcl-1.7. However I got some errors. I am searching for a long time on Google, but I still have no idea. I am a newcomer to programming. Please help me. The errors look like this:

```
In file included from /usr/include/flann/util/matrix.h:35:0,
                     from /usr/include/flann/flann.hpp:41,
                     from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/kdtree/flann.h:50,
                     from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h:45,
                     from /data2/houzhixing/Kintinuous/src/backend/DeformationGraph.h:27,
                     from /data2/houzhixing/Kintinuous/src/backend/DeformationGraph.cpp:19:
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h: In instantiation of 'static void flann::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive; T = std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >]':
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:26:30:   required from 'void flann::serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive; T = std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:35:40:   required from 'static void flann::serialization::Serializer<T>::load(InputArchive&, T&) [with InputArchive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive; T = std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:276:61:   required from 'Archive& flann::serialization::InputArchive<Archive>::operator&(T&) [with T = std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >; Archive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/lsh_table.h:319:10:   required from 'void flann::lsh::LshTable<ElementType>::serialize(Archive&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive; ElementType = float]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:18:9:   required from 'static void flann::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive; T = flann::lsh::LshTable<float>]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:26:30:   [ skipping 6 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:18:9:   required from 'static void flann::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive; T = flann::LshIndex<flann::L2_Simple<float> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:26:30:   required from 'void flann::serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive; T = flann::LshIndex<flann::L2_Simple<float> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:35:40:   required from 'static void flann::serialization::Serializer<T>::load(InputArchive&, T&) [with InputArchive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive; T = flann::LshIndex<flann::L2_Simple<float> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:276:61:   required from 'Archive& flann::serialization::InputArchive<Archive>::operator&(T&) [with T = flann::LshIndex<flann::L2_Simple<float> >; Archive = flann::serialization::LoadArchive]'
    /usr/include/flann/algorithms/lsh_index.h:204:9:   required from 'void flann::LshIndex<Distance>::loadIndex(FILE*) [with Distance = flann::L2_Simple<float>; FILE = _IO_FILE]'
    /data2/houzhixing/Kintinuous/src/backend/DeformationGraph.cpp:1054:1:   required from here
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:18:9: error: 'class std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >' has no member named 'serialize'
             type.serialize(ar);
             ^
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h: In instantiation of 'static void flann::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive; T = std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >]':
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:26:30:   required from 'void flann::serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive; T = std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:40:56:   required from 'static void flann::serialization::Serializer<T>::save(OutputArchive&, const T&) [with OutputArchive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive; T = std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:294:61:   required from 'Archive& flann::serialization::OutputArchive<Archive>::operator&(const T&) [with T = std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >; Archive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/lsh_table.h:319:10:   required from 'void flann::lsh::LshTable<ElementType>::serialize(Archive&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive; ElementType = float]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:18:9:   required from 'static void flann::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive; T = flann::lsh::LshTable<float>]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:26:30:   [ skipping 6 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:18:9:   required from 'static void flann::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive; T = flann::LshIndex<flann::L2_Simple<float> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:26:30:   required from 'void flann::serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive; T = flann::LshIndex<flann::L2_Simple<float> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:40:56:   required from 'static void flann::serialization::Serializer<T>::save(OutputArchive&, const T&) [with OutputArchive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive; T = flann::LshIndex<flann::L2_Simple<float> >]'
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:294:61:   required from 'Archive& flann::serialization::OutputArchive<Archive>::operator&(const T&) [with T = flann::LshIndex<flann::L2_Simple<float> >; Archive = flann::serialization::SaveArchive]'
    /usr/include/flann/algorithms/lsh_index.h:198:9:   required from 'void flann::LshIndex<Distance>::saveIndex(FILE*) [with Distance = flann::L2_Simple<float>; FILE = _IO_FILE]'
    /data2/houzhixing/Kintinuous/src/backend/DeformationGraph.cpp:1054:1:   required from here
    /usr/include/flann/util/serialization.h:18:9: error: 'class std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> >' has no member named 'serialize'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/backend.dir/backend/DeformationGraph.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/backend.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the library requires that a type has a `serialize` member function, it is not going to work with *any* of the C++ standard library types. You might have to read up on the requirements.

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue on different library that depends on flann and fixed by https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/issues/214

> We had a mysterious error in the serialization code if we included the flann headers after some opencv headers and used `g++ -std=c++11`. Changing the include order fixed the issue (including flann headers before any opencv headers). It seems that opencv headers leak `#define USE_UNORDERED_MAP 1` in case of std ≥ C++11. This then gets picked up by the `#if` in lsh_table.h in the original flann library.

The solution is to include flann before OpenCV.

Comment: Please include the solution in the link to your answer -- That way, if the GitHub issue or repository is ever deleted, this answer will remain valid in Stack Overflow

Comment: Still made my day in 2020 building a project with OpenCV 4.3.0 + PCL 1.11.0 and Flann 1.9.1